# ¿Cómo cargar un select de html con datos de una tabla mysql pero que te aparezca inicialmente el valor de una consulta?

Tags: php, html5

Me encuentro diseñando y desarrollando un formulario el cual su función es la de editar los datos de un item de una tabla, ya obtengo todos los datos del mismo mediante un id que es la clave primaria en la tabla y a cada uno de ellos los guardo en distintas variables. Una vez que ya he obtenido los datos los muestro en los `input type=text` en `input type=radio` y en un `<select>`.

Al ser el formulario para la edición me he encontrado con un inconveniente con el `select` ya que me gustaría que en el se muestren todas las opciones que están descritas en otra tabla que solamente contiene en este caso las descripciones de las categorías con su respectivo código pero que me aparezca inicialmente la opción que es igual a la consultada previamente y que ya ha sido grabada en otra variable.

De esta manera tengo el código html con php embebido y que es como muestro en otro formulario para la creación del item:

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
    <?php
    while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        //echo $cat;
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat['id_categoria'].','.$cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?>" ><?php echo $cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Este es el código html en el formulario para la edición del item; en este código muestro las variables en donde se han grabado los datos que originalmente tiene el item en la tabla de la base de datos.

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
    <option value="<?php echo $idCat.','.$nomCat; ?>" ><?php echo $nomCat; ?></option>
</select>
```

**¿Cómo puedo mostrar todos las opciones en el `<select>` pero que inicialmente se muestre el que es igual a las variables con los datos obtenidos en la consulta?**

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo basado en contenido concreto, usando una parte del HTML que se está generando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de los dos ejemplos que has dado, solo tendrías que concatenarlos de la siguiente forma, para que te aparescan juntos:

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
    <option value="<?php echo $idCat.','.$nomCat; ?>" ><?php echo $nomCat; ?></option>
    <?php
        while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
            //echo $cat;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat['id_categoria'].','.$cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?>" ><?php echo $cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

si lo que buscas es automatizar el opción selecta:

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
    <?php
        while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $def='';
        if($cat['id_categoria']==$idCat){
            $def='selected';
        }
            //echo $cat;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat['id_categoria'].','.$cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?>" <?php echo $def?> ><?php echo $cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

tambien hay otra manera de hacerlo (la que suelo usar yo):

```
<?php
    $buffer='';
    while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $buffer.='<option value="'.$cat['id_categoria'].','.$cat['descripcion_categoria'].'" '.(($cat['id_categoria']==$idCat)?'selected':'').' >'.$cat['descripcion_categoria'].'</option>';
    }
?>
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
    <?=$buffer?>
</select>
```

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, me funciono pero se repiten dos veces la misma categoría y por lo que veo eso siempre va a suceder, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que cuando tu abres el select para escoger una opción solo se muestre una vez todas las opciones, sin embargo que quede seleccionada la que sea igual al valor de la variable del código que previamente la he guardado.

Comment: ahora si estamos hablando, déjame actualizar es facil tambien

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro verifica y me dices si te funciona ...

Comment: si me funciono, gracias por enseñarme

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro agregue otra opción ....

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro que tal la ultima version???

Comment: Bien, me resulto al principio un poco difícil de comprender paro ya repasándolo se aclararon los cuestionamientos; muchas gracias por tu ayuda